# css text in border and border under text

Tags: css

Hi there I am new to css and to stackoverflow and need some help. I am trying to create something like this with css:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPD9i.png)

But I really don't get these results, can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Please see [ask] and post a [mcve] in your question showing us what you've tried and where you got stuck. If you haven't started coding anything yet, then SO isn't the place to begin.

Comment: Please, post code if you want some helps

Comment: sorry, next time! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a snippet which looks like the image you were trying to re-create. Hope it helps.

Useful links - 
[::after / ::before](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/), [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.hr-sect {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.hr-sect::before,
.hr-sect::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 2px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.hr-sect,
span {
  color: blue;
}

.hr-sect::before,
.hr-sect::after {
  background-color: blue;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.big {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="hr-sect"><span>HOW TO GET</span></div>
  <span class="big">GALAXY SKIN FORTNITE</span>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: @Boldbyte Don't forget to accept the answer. Happy coding!